# Ionic IOS build failed after Xcode update

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, ionic3, cocoapods

I work in Ionic 3 Application and works without any issues.  I had to update XCode and after the update, I got the Application stopped working.

Also I had to update the OS. As well, reading the forums, I updated Ionic and Cordova. But no clue what is wrong. Below is the trace.

**Command**: `*ionic cordova build ios --vebrose*`

**Log**:

```
ionic-app-scripts build --target cordova --platform ios
[21:43:03]  ionic-app-scripts 3.1.8 
[21:43:03]  build dev started ... 
[21:43:03]  clean started ... 
[21:43:03]  clean finished in 10 ms 
[21:43:03]  copy started ... 
[21:43:03]  deeplinks started ... 
[21:43:03]  deeplinks finished in 318 ms 
[21:43:03]  transpile started ... 
[21:43:08]  transpile finished in 5.40 s 
[21:43:08]  preprocess started ... 
[21:43:08]  preprocess finished in 1 ms 
[21:43:08]  webpack started ... 
[21:43:09]  copy finished in 5.90 s 
[21:43:15]  webpack finished in 6.05 s 
[21:43:15]  sass started ... 
Without `from` option PostCSS could generate wrong source map and will not find Browserslist config. Set it to CSS file path or to `undefined` to prevent this warning.
[21:43:16]  sass finished in 1.64 s 
[21:43:16]  postprocess started ... 
[21:43:16]  postprocess finished in 14 ms 
[21:43:16]  lint started ... 
[21:43:16]  build dev finished in 13.58 s 
[21:43:21]  lint finished in 4.68 s 
> cordova build ios
Building for iPhone XS Max Simulator
Building project: /Users/ustuser/Documents/c2mobileV2-WB/c2mobile/platforms/ios/c2mobile.xcworkspace
    Configuration: Debug
    Platform: emulator
Build settings from command line:
    CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR = /Users/ustuser/Documents/c2mobileV2-WB/c2mobile/platforms/ios/build/emulator
    SDKROOT = iphonesimulator12.0
    SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR = /Users/ustuser/Documents/c2mobileV2-WB/c2mobile/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch

Build settings from configuration file '/Users/ustuser/Documents/c2mobileV2-WB/c2mobile/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig':
    CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES = YES
    CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS = $(PROJECT_DIR)/$(PROJECT_NAME)/Entitlements-$(CONFIGURATION).plist
    CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = iPhone Developer
    ENABLE_BITCODE = NO
    GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = $(inherited) COCOAPODS=1
    HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = "$(TARGET_BUILD_DIR)/usr/local/lib/include" "$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/include" "$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/$(PLATFORM_NAME)/include" "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)"
    LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) '@executable_path/Frameworks' '@loader_path/Frameworks'
    OTHER_LDFLAGS = -ObjC
    PODS_BUILD_DIR = ${BUILD_DIR}
    PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR = ${PODS_BUILD_DIR}/$(CONFIGURATION)$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME)
    PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH = ${SRCROOT}/.
    PODS_ROOT = ${SRCROOT}/Pods
    SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER = $(PROJECT_DIR)/$(PROJECT_NAME)/Bridging-Header.h
```

Also reading forums, I installed CocoaPods. Also executed the following commands inside platform / ios

```
pod disintegrate
pod install
pod init
```

Below are my environment details.

```
OS version - macOS High Sierra, Version 10.13.6
XCode version - Version 10.0 (10A255)
Ionic CLI version - 4.2.1
Cordova version - 8.1.1
NPM version - 5.6.0
Node version - 8.11.1
Angular CLI version - 6.2.4
```

Comment: Could you please take a look at **[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52385600/ionic-ios-build-fails-error-archive-not-found)**?

Comment: It helps but didn't work completely. It still gives error in  "/platforms/ios/build/emulator/ - ld: library not found for -lstdc++.6 ". I then downgraded my Xcode, Cordova and Ionic but still facing the same issue.

Comment: Typo: should be `--verbose` instead of `--vebrose`. And no `*` in the command.