# Ionic3 error on build ios Promise rejected with non-error: 'Error code 65

Tags: iphone, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to create an ipa file but I have this unreadable error
when I run this command line on my Mac

```
ionic cordova build ios --prod --release
```

> CordovaError: **Promise rejected with non-error: 'Error code 65 for
>   command:** xcodebuild with args:
>   -exportArchive,-archivePath,MyApp.xcarchive,-exportOptionsPlist,/Users/FSE/myApp04/platforms/ios/exportOptions.plist,-exportPath,/Users/FSE/myApp04/platforms/ios/build/device'
>       at cli.catch.err (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova:30:15)
>       at process.internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:77:7)

Ionic:

```
ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.3.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0
```

Cordova:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
Cordova Platforms     : ios 4.5.5
Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.2.0, (and 4 other plugins)
```

System:

```
ios-deploy : 1.9.4
NodeJS     : v11.0.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
npm        : 6.4.1
OS         : macOS
Xcode      : Xcode 10.1 Build version 10B61
```

Comment: This is related to xcode 10
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52385600/ionic-ios-build-fails-error-archive-not-found/52388081

Comment: This has been fixed in the latest Cordova iOS release https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2019/02/09/cordova-ios-release-5.0.0.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've solved it like this

```
ionic cordova build ios -- --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"
```

Comment: Tried this but still having the same error.

Comment: This is my system info
Ionic:
   Ionic CLI          : 5.4.16
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.10
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4

Cordova:
   Cordova CLI       : 8.1.1 (cordova-lib@8.1.0)
   Cordova Platforms : ios 4.4.0
   Cordova Plugins   : no whitelisted plugins (31 plugins total)

Utility:
   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : 1.6.0

System:
   NodeJS            : v12.22.12 (/Users/aeologic/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.12/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.14.16
   OS                : macOS Monterey
   Xcode             : Xcode 13.4.1 Build version 13F100

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is correct. You can also put in build.json file:

```
{
    "ios": {
        "release": {
            ...,
            "buildFlag": [
                "-UseModernBuildSystem=0"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

either

`ionic cordova build ios -- --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"`
or just open

> xcode -> File -> Workspace Settings

and change build system to "Legacy Build System"

Answer (score 1):

In my experience the "buildFlag" is not enough, I mean I had:

```
"ionic cordova run ios -- --buildFlag=\"-UseModernBuildSystem=0\""
```

... but I was still getting the Error code 65.

To solve the issue you must open the project you find inside "yourproject/platforms/ios" in xcode and check that the signing certificate is ok. To do so just click on the project (first icon on the top-left panel) and check the "Signing" section.

Answer (score 0):

For newer version of xcode, you have to have Legacy Build System. If you already have the Legacy Build System, then uncheck the automatic signing and recheck it. Don't know why but it worked for me.